# enum class and boost serialization

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost, enum-class

How can I serialize/deserialize a `class` that has a member of `enum class` using boost serialization. Example:

```
enum class enum_class{
    item1=0,item2=1
}

class foo{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    foo() = default;
    ~foo() = default;
    template<class Archive> inline void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & a;
        ar & b;
    }
    enum_class a;
    int b;
};
```

I can not make the `enum_class` serializable since it does not accept `friend` or `member functions`. what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your enum class serializable.

See [tutotial, non-intrusive version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion) for instructions.

Comment: I could find anything about enum class. just enums and classes. nothing for enum classes

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Implement the non-intrusive version for your enum.

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin I see thanks